# Create PySpark dataframe : sequence of months with year

Tags: date, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Complete newbie here.

I would like to create a **dataframe** using **pyspark** that will list month and year taking the current date and listing **x** number of lines.

if i decide `x=5` dataframe should like as below

**Calendar_Entry**

```
August 2019<br/>
September 2019<br/>
October 2019<br/>
November 2019<br/>
December 2019
```

Answer (score 1):

Spark is not a tool for generating rows in a distributed way but rather for processing then distributed.
Since your data is small anyway the best solution is probably to create the data in pure python and if required create a spark dataframe out of it.

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta


def create_months_df(n_months):
    date_list = [datetime.datetime.today() - relativedelta(months=i) for i in range(n_months)]
    dates_formatted = [(d.strftime("%B"), d.year) for d in date_list]
    return spark.createDataFrame(dates_formatted, ["month", "year"])
```